# Jquery / HTML - Table structure issues with dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Wokring a report page where I pull my data via ajax and then organize them by day of the week. I got some help from this forum to get this up and running but missing one small issue I cant figure out.

Everything is smashed into one big table. I was hoping to divide have one table per day of the week and then nested tables per entries. Having a tough time figure out of to organize this with the code im using.

Here an example of what im trying to get:

```
(table)
-----------------------------------
 Monday - May 2nd - 2016
-----------------------------------
(table)
Entry 1 
Description
Date: 2016-05-02 09:45
(/table)
-----------------------------------
(br)(br)

(table)
Entry 2 
Description
Date: 2016-05-02 10:55
-----------------------------------
(/table)
(br)(br)

(/table)    


(table)
-----------------------------------
Tuesday - May 3rd - 2016
-----------------------------------

(table)
-----------------------------------
Entry 3
Description
Date: 2016-05-03 11:55
-----------------------------------
(/table)
(br)(br)

(table)
-----------------------------------
Entry 4
Description
Date: 2016-05-03 13:55
-----------------------------------
(/table)
(br)(br)

(/table)

 ...
```

Here an example of the code I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/vLdn68ko/14/

```
var items_by_date  = {}; // declare an object that will have date indexes
$.ajax({url:"/SomeUrlBeginninWithSlash",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

      data.d.results.map(function(item){
        var item_date = moment(item.Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        // if the date index does not exist we need to declare it
        if(!items_by_date[item_date]) items_by_date[item_date] = [item];
        // else we can just push the item on that array
        else items_by_date[item_date].push(item);
      })

      console.log(items_by_date);
      // now you can render how ever you need to
      drawTable(items_by_date);
    }
});

function drawTable(data){
  $('#dataTable').html('');
  for(var d in data){ // d will be the date index
    $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">'+d+'</td></tr>');

    data[d].map(function(item){
      $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td>'+item.ID+'</td><td>'+item.Description+'</td></tr>');
    })
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the ajax call back:

```
responseText: {
    d: {
        results: [{
            ID: "1",
            Description: "Test1",
            Date: "2016-05-02 09:45"
        }, {
            ID: "2",
            Description: "Test2",
            Date: "2016-05-02 10:45"
        }, {
            ID: "3",
            Description: "Test3",
            Date: "2016-05-03 11:45"
        }, {
            ID: "4",
            Description: "Test4",
            Date: "2016-05-04 11:45",
        }]
    }
}
```

Would anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you post what the data returned form the ajax call looks like?

Comment: I added an example of the ajax return.

Comment: You could create a new table and add the rows to it inside the loop in `drawTable` instead of erasing the content of `#dataTable` and then adding all the rows to it.